# Why can't use certain fields and keyof in a type definition

Tags: typescript

This is my type definition code:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

type Bar = {
    [prop in keyof Foo]?: number | string;
};

type Bar2 = {
    id: string;
    [prop in keyof Foo]?: number | string;
};
```

Definition with `Bar` is OK, but there is something wrong with `Bar2`, is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the `[K in keys]` syntax can't be mixed with a classic key / type definition, but you can do:

```
type Bar2 = Bar & {
    id: string
}
```